Laravel 11 behing nginx and aws alb not rendering correctly the blade urls
My laravel application is running inside an ec2 that has nginx listening to port 80
the traffic is redirected through aws application load balancer that redirect all traffic coming from port 80 to port 443
when i enter the application it appears as secured on chrome toolbar
however some of the pages are not and i notice that the blade template is rendering the urls as http
on my blade template for example i have
<form name="form" method="post" class="form-validation"
                    action="<?= route('backend.auth.login.post') ?>">

which renders to
<form name="form" method="post" class="form-validation" action="http://admin.myDomain.com/login"></form>

why is it not rendered to https and how can i force it?

There are multiple things to consider. If I give you a heads up, check URLs are forced to HTTPS (URL::forceScheme('https');), and in nginx, make sure ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key are added. Google it. You might get hints on these
